# Excel - Get R1C1 Reference Style Option in Quick Access Toolbar (QAT Bar)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to get **R1C1 Reference Style** Option in **Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)** Bar in Microsoft Excel?

[image: r1c1 notation in QAT bar]

Answer (score 3):

You can access that option with this shortcut (not really short, but still):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want it slightly shorter, add the Options: Formulas command to the QAT:

[image]

Depending on where you position it, the shortcut would then be (if it's in the first position on the QAT):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. seems like this is the closest workaround.